# Making jQuery slideUp when clicking off

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to make a nav slideDown. I want when people click anywhere outside of the nav it slideUp.

The problem is that with my code it slideUp even if I click on the element. I basically want it to slideUp if the user clicks anywhere other than the element which slideDown

```
 //News Drop Down
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li.newsDrop').mouseenter(function () {
    $('div.newsadviceDrop').slideDown('medium');
});
});

$('body').click(function() {
    $('div.newsadviceDrop').slideUp('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
   });
});
```

Comment: does the li.newsdrop contains some text? if it does you can do like my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This it wath I would do:

```
$('*').not("li.newsDrop").click(function() {
    $('div.newsadviceDrop').slideUp('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':not([attr="value"])').click(function() {
$('div.newsadviceDrop').slideUp('slow', function() {
// Animation complete.
```

});

in not your li element..so the other elements besides your li would be selected